# Django testing - use separate database for TransactionTestCase

Tags: python, django, testing, django-testing, django-database

I need to test Django application behavior for concurrent requests. I need to test is database data correct after that. As a cnclusion, I need to test and transactions mechanism. So let's use `TransactionTestCase` for that.

I spawned requests to database using threading and got 'DatabaseError: no such table: app_modelname exception' in threads because of automatic switching to in-memory database type (for SQLite by Django when running test).

Of course, I can specify `'TEST_NAME'` for `'default'` key in `settings.DATABASES`, and test will pass as expected. But this also used for all tests too, so tests running takes a much more time.

- I thought about custom database router, but it seems to be very
  hackish way to do that since I need to patch / mock a lot of
  attributes in models to define is this executed in
  `TransactionTestCase` or not.
- There was also idea to use
  `override_settings` but unfortunately it does not work (see
  [issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19031) for details)

How I can specify (or create) **not** in-memory database (on hard drive) for just a few test cases (`TransactionTestCase`) and left others to run with in-memory database?

Any thoughts, ideas or code samples will be appreciated. 
Thanks!